# Visit to GA shows in real time but not 7 hours later

Tags: google-analytics

I added Google Analytics to my website today. When I added the code to the `<head>` section of my document this morning (at 10:00 am EST) i immediately checked the RealTime section of Google Analytics and saw my visit was registered, and I checked it for every page of my website. Everything worked according to expectations (I used Google Analytics in this past).

Now, at 5 p.m. EST (7 hours later), I went to view today's visits and it's showing no visitors. What I did to check today's visits in the Audience Overview was to set the date from Nov 3 to Nov 3 like this

```
Nov 3, 2017-Nov 3, 2017
```

It's showing no visitors for today (7 hours later)

Question: how long after a visit should it show in Google Analytics? and if you expect that one visit to be showing by now, then what could be the problem?

(Update: the only thing I might have done i.e. changed after my real time visit was to set the property of the default URL to HTTPS rather than HTTP)

Comment: Can you way 24 hours and check again?   Google Analytics usually processes data into reports completely within 24 hours although occasionally I've seen it take 2 or 3 days.

Answer (score 3):

Real time in Google Analytics can be especially useful to make sure that you have implemented tracking information correctly by sending test traffic & using real time to check for the visit.

However, Google Analytic's processing latency is anywhere between 24-48 hours.

The last bit of information that you provided could be key. Have you implemented a forced redirect to the https version of your site? Additionally, have you updated your property to reflect the https version intended for tracking?

It's important to chose between www and non-www, which can be accomplished by adding your site to Google Console, setting the preferred version of your site in Google console, and finally be sure to sync it with analytics (under your property settings).

Additionally, it is prudent to redirect users to both the SSL version of your site, as well as your preferred "www" or "non-www" version. Setting the preferred version will only affect Google Search results, bot not other search engines. Check these items off & get back with me if you don't see an improvement with data collection.